# What is the best way to transition from imp to importlib for CloudLinux Passenger WSGI files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, passenger, pylint

I am looking for the best way to transition from `imp` to `importlib` with my `passenger_wsgi.py` file using `importlib` as recommended by `pylint`.

My passenger file looks like this:

```
import imp
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

wsgi = imp.load_source('wsgi', 'core/wsgi.py')
application = wsgi.application
```

I have seen some examples using `importlib.utils.find_spec(path)` and some using `importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('name','script')`

Does anyone have an example for their passenger_wsgi.py file that uses the newer method with importlib that would be the new standard they could share?